# How can I use mongodb with linq for store large binary objects(files)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, norm

I know two most popular C# drivers for mongodb, this are [mongodb-csharp](http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp) and [NoRM](http://github.com/atheken/NoRM). Both of them have some problems. For example, with mongodb-csharp I can't use full functional linq and with NoRM I can't store large file in mongodb. In my project, I need to use linq with large objects (files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check official 10gen's MongoDB C# [driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver). It doesn't support LINQ yet, but they added really nice [query mechanism](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Driver/GridFS/MongoGridFS.cs) for GridFS.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I didn't read the question title, sorry.  I don't think you'd want to use Linq for talking with GridFS.  If so, we'd be happy for some contributions.

---

The linq driver to mongodb-csharp is almost done.  It supports projections, conditions, ordering, skip, take, and (almost ready) it will build map-reduce queries when you use an aggregate and/or group by statements.

If you grab the latest typedcollections branch, I think you'll find it does most everything you need.

http://wiki.github.com/craiggwilson/mongodb-csharp/linq

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you **need** to use LINQ. Using LINQ is handy but it is not necessary.

A solution is to help the teams who are developing those drivers. It is all open source so you can join those teams.